Getting Build failed in Android Studio flutter project
Getting an error message when trying to run the app after adding google_sigh_in dependency.
Running application on pixel 7 Api 30 and encountering this error.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':google_sign_in_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\User.jdks\corretto-11.0.24\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-3\01761d3d44a592c784df1715afe57f9c\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-3\01761d3d44a592c784df1715afe57f9c\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

Java and gradle version
JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
gradle-8.3-all.zip
pubspec dependency i used
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6
provider: ^6.1.2
wakelock_plus: ^1.2.8
firebase_core: ^3.6.0
firebase_auth: ^5.3.1
animations: ^2.0.11
google_sign_in: ^6.2.1

please inform your java and gradle version

JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
gradle-8.3-all.zip

I fixed this issue by downgrading jdk to version 17,
just download jdk17 and run
flutter config --jdk-dir "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17"
